# Building a system with Apache ActiveMQ and MQTT protocol for large number of devices?

Tags: activemq-classic, mqtt, jms-topic

I'm building a system with large devices using ActiveMQ and MQTT protocol, the model which I'm using on standalone server contains two applications as follows:

- App1: Enterprise app received messages from large number of device:
  Devices publish to server through topic every 3 minutes:
  [Devices] --- MQTT protocol --> [ActiveMQ] --- Openwire protocol --> [Glassfish with EJB using MDB to subscribe topic] --> Oracle DB
- App2: Enterprise app scan command from Oracle DB and send to large number of device:
  Every device subscribe a unique topic like: device.0000001, then server will publish to this topic when have command from server for device
  [Large number of devices] <--- MQTT --- [ActiveMQ] <--- Openwire -- [Glassfish with EJB timer scan and publish] <-- Oracle DB  <-- Web with commands

You can help me about the enterprise model to support large number of devices using multi-servers? The temporary solution for App1: I'm using random a server from list ActiveMQ servers to connect and publish message. And every server, I'm deploying standalone ActiveMQ and App1 to subscribe messages.

But the App2: I'm building only one server to scan and publish message.

The question for that the best model which server can to publish to ActiveMQ which device connect to? Can convert message topic to queue then using network of brokers and multi App1 to handle unique message?

Answer (score 2):

MQTT protocol uses a pub/sub model with topics only, not queues, so you need to scale topics.

ActiveMQ supports various models for scaling out: Master Slave, Networks of Brokers:
http://activemq.apache.org/clustering.html

For better handling of scaling out you can also consider to implement Enterprise Integration Patterns by using Apache Camel to route messages to and from ActiveMQ 
http://camel.apache.org/how-does-camel-work-with-activemq.html